# Tomcat7 with maven, contextReloadable not getting applied

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

In my `pom.xml`, I have the following profile :

```
      <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>webProject</finalName>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I am running tomcat with the following command from my command line:

`mvn clean tomcat7:run -Plocal`

Everything works great except when I edit and save my java files (using intellij) nothing happens. The app doesn't reload at all. I have tried waiting and refreshing, but nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Here is my `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a simple fix. Ill share it if anyone has the same problem. The problem was Intellij was not compiling the java files.

To get this to work, I had to go `Build->Compile... (ctrl+Shift+F9)`.

Or, you can go to `File ->Settings->Compiler->make project automatically` and Intellij will do it automatically.

Comment: InteliJ can understand if there is change in bytecode classes, not in the sources. So when you run manually compile, or run test InteliJ makes compilation and finds that there is change and trigger recompilation. Other wise nothing happens.